# Quiz application using jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

Sorry for asking this question. I was searching for past few hours but could not find any help.

I want to make a simple quiz application using JSP.
I created 2 tables as below

1. Col1: QuizId Col2: Quiz Name Col3: Number of Questions
2. Col1: QtnNum Col2: Question Col3: Option1 Col4: Option2 Col5: Option3 Col6: Option4 Col7: CorrectOption

The page will appear like below image.

[image]

the code for this page is

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*,java.io.*,java.text.*,java.util.*  ,javax.servlet.*,javax.servlet.http.*" 
 %> 
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
     pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <HTML>
   <head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
       <link rel="stylesheet" 
       href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
       integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bstyle.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
   </head>
     <body>
  <body>
  <%            
String quiz_title =request.getParameter("quiz_title");
String no_question =request.getParameter("no_question");
String quiz_id=request.getParameter("quiz_id");
   %>
       <br><br>
      <div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <h3><%=quiz_title %></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <h3>Total no. of questions: <%=no_question %></h3>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<%
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student_portal 2.0","root","");
Statement st=con.createStatement();
String sql="select * from quiz_q_a where quiz_id="+quiz_id;
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next())
{
    String question =rs.getString("question");
    String option_a =rs.getString("option_a");
    String option_b =rs.getString("option_b");
    String option_c =rs.getString("option_c");
    String option_d =rs.getString("option_d");
    String correct_option =rs.getString("correct_option");
    String explanation =rs.getString("explanation");
    String current_no =rs.getString("q_no");    
%>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <h4><%=current_no%>.  <%=question %></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <h4>    &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;(&emsp;)
        </h4>
    </div>
</div>  
<br>
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" value="A">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">A. <%=option_a %></label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" value="B">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">B. <%=option_b %></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" value="C">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">C. <%=option_c %></label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" value="D">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">D. <%=option_d %></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <hr>
</form> 
<%
}
%>  
   </div>
    <br>

     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
     DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
   </script>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" 
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    
     </body>
      </html>
```

My requirement is to add a submit button at the end of the page. On clicking the submit button, the user response should be stored in an array. The selected answers from the user response array should be compared against the correct answers array from the table and calculate the score.

Please help me to achieve this. I am not able to capture the user response. Thanks.

Comment: add `action` attribute for `form` in order to store/process `values`. This might be helpful https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp (in your case receiver will be jsp/servlet)

Comment: yes I tried that but when I add a button inside the form the button is repeated again for 5 times as I only need submit at the end once someone clicks on it all the 5 question answers should pass

Comment: Think you did something wrong, `form` should aggregate all answers so send all with submit ! (as I see)

Comment: like as im using loop we need to work on javascript and somewhere to store results 
like if I'm doing something wrong please let me know and help me thank you

Comment: no javascript required, send via form the values to a jsp and from there process

Comment: Like according to my idea as im getting questions and options from database and using a loop to print them all only one options is being seleceted

Comment: sir if u dont mind can i contact u somewhere so u can test and check whats the issue

Comment: can talk here ... if u don't get an answer i will post one latter

Comment: other option is store locally the value (into a js-array) an on some button (just check local_array with values form db-> stored also in js after fetch) (here no action needed)

Comment: does `q_no` are in sequence ? Also , `correct_option` will have value `A,B..` ?

Comment: @Traian GEICU yes can us send a sample code for it as I'm new to js

Comment: yes @swathi q_no are in sequence 1 to 5 (for above example) and correct_option indicates A if option a is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `<form>` tag and `submit` button outside the `while-loop` .Also, as the radio button have same value currently in your form so to uniquely identify each radio you can use `current_no` with the name of your radio-button i.e : `name="inlineRadioOptions_<%=current_no%>"` .So your jsp code will look like below :

```
 <form method="post" action="your_url">
     <%
    //your connection codes
    while(rs.next())
    {
       //other codes
          String current_no =rs.getString("q_no");    
    %>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h4><%=current_no%>.  <%=question %></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <h4>    &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;(&emsp;)
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <br>
    <form>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_<%=current_no%>" value="A">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">A. <%=option_a %></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_<%=current_no%>" value="B">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">B. <%=option_b %></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_<%=current_no%>"  value="C">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">C. <%=option_c %></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_<%=current_no%>"  value="D">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">D. <%=option_d %></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <hr>
    <%
    }
    %>  
//will have value of quiz_id
  <input type="hidden" name-"quiz_id" value="<%=quiz_id%>">
    //added button
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Then , at your server side you need to use again `select` query to fetch result depending on the `quiz_id` and check if the user answer and correct_answer are same or not depending on this increment values . i.e :

```
<!--your connection codes-->
 //to get no coorect and wrong answer
int wrong = 0, correct = 0;
//getting quiz_id
String quiz_id = request.getParameter("quiz_id");
String sql = "select * from quiz_q_a where quiz_id=" + quiz_id;
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
while (rs.next()) {
 //get correct option for 1st ,2 ..etc
 String correct_option = rs.getString("correct_option");
 //get current question..
 String current_no = rs.getString("q_no");
 //get user answer
 String answers = request.getParameter("inlineRadioOptions_" + current_no);
 //check if equal
 if (answers.equals(correct_option)) {
  correct++; //increment

 } else {

  wrong++; //increment
 }
}
out.println("Correct Answer are" + correct);
out.println("Wrong Answer are" + wrong);
```

Comment: Got it, ma'am, Thanks a lot ma'am understood the thing which I was doing wrong.
Again thanks for suck a great explanation.